# php array_map to every 'arr' element in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array:

```
[
 [
  'arr1' => 'string',
  'arr2' => 5000000,
  ...//hundreds of other elements which I want to preserve
 ],
 [
  'arr1' => 'string2',
  'arr2' => 4000000,
  ...//other elements
 ]
]
```

I need to divide only every `arr2` element by 10000 or apply `intval` to it. I tried to use `array_map` or `array_walk` but it said I need to pass an array to it while I tried to pass it a certain element. Also these functions work with every element while I need to work only with 1 element in subarray. There may be hundreds of other elements in subarray which I need to preserve. Thank you.

Comment: Add the codes that you have tried so far.

Comment: `array_map(function ($a) { $a['arr2'] /= 10000; return $a; }, $array)`…?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use array_walk() http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php like this :

```
array_walk($yourarray, function(&$value) {
   if(isset($value['arr2']) && is_string($value['arr2'])){ // or test numeric is_numeric()
     $value['arr2'] = intval($value['arr2']); // or divide $value['arr2']/1000 
   }
});
```